# VerticalAlignment in WrapPanel - How to make it work correctly?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, datatemplate, vertical-alignment, wrappanel

I am having a kinda strange problem.

Here is the situation. I have a `ListView`, with a custom defined `GroupStyle` to make data appear in `Expander`s, in which there is a `WrapPanel` containing `StackPanels` (which contain one ToggleButton + one custom control)
The custom control in the `StackPanel` is not visible by default, and becomes visible when the `ToggleButton` is checked.
However, when I check a `ToggleButton`, the custom control appears, and all the other control situated on the same line will move to a vertical center.
Ideally, I'd like these other members to stay on top. I've tried to set `VerticalAlignment="Top"` everywhere I could, it doesn't change anyway.

Imaged problem:

The initial state of an expander:

[image: Expander before]

Once the `ToggleButton` is clicked, here is what happens:

[image: Expander after]

As you can see, the button "Test Analysis" is moved to stay at the center. I want it to stay in the same place than the original.

Moreover, I've defined all of these styles in separate `DataTemplate`s objects.
Here is some light code (I just removed what's useless for the problem here, won't make you read tons of XAML code :) ):

The expander's content property:

```
<Expander.Content>
    <WrapPanel Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ItemsPresenter VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</Expander.Content>
```

The list's `ItemsPanel` :

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate >
    <WrapPanel 
         Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth),
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                         AncestorType=Expander}}"
         ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth,
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"

         ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight,
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

The list's `ItemsTemplate` :

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
    <ToggleButton BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" IsChecked="{Binding Value.IsToLaunch, Mode=TwoWay}"
              Command="{Binding DataContext.UpdateGroupCheckingsCommand,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
        <Grid Background="Transparent">
            <!-- Blah blah blah about the ToggleButton's content -->

        </Grid>
    </ToggleButton>

    <my:UcReleaseChooser>
        <!-- Blah blah blah about being visible if ToggleButton is Checked -->
    </my:UcReleaseChooser>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting the verticalalignment property to Top or the VerticalContentAlignment property of the listview to Stretch

```
   <Style TargetType="ListView">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    </Style>
```

or

```
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Thumbs up! Works like a dream, that was the only property I hadn't tried to change. Thanks again!